# Script to split a folder with thousands of (audio) files into subfolders of 74 minutes each

Tags: bash, powershell, batch

I have a folder with ~1600+ mp3 files, and i want to organize it in multiple *"albums"*, i.e. subfolders where the total duration of the audio files inside doesn't exceed **74 minutes** (the size of an Audio CD, for the sake of organization in my Windows Media Player library, not with intention to burn all of these in a physical CD).

So i need to make a script (that can either be Bash - i have WSL installed, Windows Batch - doubt that could achive what i'm looking for, or PowerShell) that loops through all of the ~1600+ files, and start moving them to a subfolder, like `Volume 1`. When this subfolder is near exceeding the 74-minute limit, it should create a new subfolder (eg. `Volume 2`) and resume moving to that folder instead, next to `Volume 3` and so on.

The reason i'm asking here is because, although i have some idea about how logically this bash script should operate, i don't know how to get the duration of an audio file, let alone control the flow to switch folders when the 74-minute limit is hit (or about to be hit).

Comment: Should the script process files in some order? (what order then?). Or do you want it to [optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) the "albums" by rearranging freely?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski in the specific case i'm trying to solve, no need to follow a specific order, althrough those files will come with sequential number (eg. 0001, 0002...) in the filename

Comment: "Windows Media Player". Is this on Windows then? Are you interested in a Linux solution?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski either. I mentioned bash in the title because i have WSL installed and Bash seems far more capable than Windows Batch. But even a PowerShell script would help me. I will update the question to reflect this insight. DONE

Answer (score 0):

A [CD of ~650 MB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-ROM) holding MP3 files can hold about ten **hours** in terms of playing time.

You state you have MP3 files, and [that format significantly compresses audio](https://higherhz.com/lossless-vs-lossy-compression-audio-formats/), with some loss of fidelity. If you were to use an **uncompressed** audio format such as WAV or PCM, you would, indeed, be limited to about 74 minutes per CD. Using a **lossless, compressed** format such as APE or FLAC, you could get yet more on the CD. MP3 sacrifices a bit of absolute fidelity for higher compression yet.

It would be pointless to burn an audio-format CD, since you cannot get back information already lost to MP3 compression. On the other hand, *almost all* CD players made in recent times **can play MP3 files**, as-is, on a data disc. Simply create a CD *data* disc, holding 650 MB of MP3 files. There's absolutely no need to know the performance *length*, just the number of MB to be stored, leaving a little extra room if there are many small files, because a bit of space is wasted in the last sector of each file.

Comment: I cited the 70 minute limit not because i plan to burn the whole 1600+ songs to CD, but because i want to separate them to make albuns on Windows Media Player. That's it. Was just a perfeccionist choice.

Answer (score 0):

-- This will be a mix of actual and pseudo code --

In Powershell, to get the Length of an MP3 file we can use this excellent [Display Extended File Attributes](https://powershellmagazine.com/2015/04/13/pstip-use-shell-application-to-display-extended-file-attributes/) function:

```
$dir_nam = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Folder"
$nam_len = Get-ExtensionAttribute -FullName $dir_nam -ExtensionAttribute Filename, Length  
## This will populate the $nam_len variable with the FullName, Filename & Length for each file in the directory.
```

In addition to the 74 minute max size, you will also need to set a minimum minute size (I am going to use 70 minutes). Next we need to know the average length of each file so we can tell about how many will fit within the 70-74 time limits.

```
foreach ($tim in ($nam_len | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Length)){
$secs = ([TimeSpan]::Parse($tim)).TotalSeconds # converts each value to seconds
$totl = $totl + $secs}  # Sum (length) of all the MP3s (in seconds)

$avg = ($totl/($nam_len.Count))/60 # (total seconds/number of MP3s)/60 seconds = average length in minutes
$num_mp3s = [math]::floor(72/$avg) # average number of MP3s in 72 minutes
```

Now work on the loop which is here in pseudo code:

```
## Make this into a loop 
$batch = $nam_len | Sort-Object {Get-Random} | Select-Object -first $num_mp3s # Randomly select the avg number of MP3's
If ($batch).Length -gt 70 # Make sure the sum (length) is > 70 minutes
-and 
($batch).Length -lt 74){  # Make sure the sum (length) is < 74 minutes
    Create Directory X++ # Create a new directory
    Move $batch.FullName to Directory X++ 
    }
Else (Loop-Again)
Execute the Loop = (total number of MP3s/$num_mp3s) or until all files have been placed.
```

As you get near the end you may have to reduce the minimum minutes to finish.